# Why is Guava's EventBus marked unstable in IntelliJ 2018.2?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

A new inspection was added in IntelliJ  2018.2 which should warn from unstable APIs:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159541.

This warning shows up for the Guava's EventBus. Why is this an unstable API?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Because [the `EventBus` class](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/26.0-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html) is annotated as `@Beta`.

[You'd have to ask the Guava project maintainers](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3360) why a class that exists for 16 versions of Guava is still Beta, but it still is.

Comment: @GhostCat no, I haven't automated anything. I tend to add close votes without any comment more and more.

Comment: `a class that exists for 16 versions of Guava is still Beta` Wowzers. I'm here because Guava's `Hashing` class is also marked as `@Beta`. I wonder if it's the same case. Anyway, haven't had any trouble with it so far.

Comment: 22 versions and counting! ;)

Comment: The reason for this, is because they reserve the freedom to continue changing the API without being held responsible for breaking the world: See the docs on `@Beta` annotation :D

Comment: @Decoded You should avoid all uses of `@Beta` stuff in production. If half of Guava is `@Beta` Guava is half as useful as you'd expect. So by keeping a lot of stuff in `@Beta` for several release you effectively say "This is a toy project" instead of "this is production ready and robust". Freedom has its costs.

Comment: I absolutely agree it has a cost. Not suggesting rules of use in or out of production.  Although, I work at LinkedIn. We have services that have half a million QPS and use guava stream processing, etc. and they are stable. If it works for your use case, use it if you understand the risks. Whenever we bump guava version, we risk introducing some bug, and if it happens we rollback, and fix.

Comment: It looks like the `@Beta` annotation has been removed, but the maintainers are recommending against using `EventBus`
See [this issue](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3360) and the related commits for more context.
[Remove `@Beta` from EventBus](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/3360)

[Remove `@Beta` from EventBus and related classes.](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/781ac8a447256fe0185ffdecd0fc993bbf84889f)

[Discourage usage of EventBus.](https://github.com/google/guava/commit/82a3ecf42cf63f2ea4db5c605d80c4478d8877ae)

Answer (score 16):

Besides @JB Nizet's answer that perfectly explains why IntelliJ flags this error, you may also want to **suppress it** globally but only **for the Google Beta annotations**.

Just go to `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> JVM languages` as per the picture below and, if you feel like it, delete the `com.google.common.anotations.Beta`.

[image: how to disable IntelliJ's Google Beta annotation]

Answer (score 9):

You can also ask IntelliJ to suppress the warning for the definition of your `@Beta` annotated class as follows:

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnstableApiUsage")
static RateLimiter API_RATE_LIMITER = RateLimiter.create(8);
```

This properly deals with the warning in a particular case when you're okay with using the class anyway (and don't run into issues).

Answer (score 1):

EventBus class is marked with the `@com.google.common.annotations.Beta` annotation. So I think the inspection is triggering on that. See: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html